# Remove items from list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to remove items from list matching ids:

The list is:

```
IList<FeatureDto> featuresDto
```

The featureDto is

```
public class FeatureDto
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The format of the Id's I receive is:

```
selectedFeatureIds = "4,5,6"
```

I need to remove from the `IList<FeatureDto> featuresDto` the id's of the string selectedFeatureIds.

Comment: Okay, so that doesn't sound too hard... but we could do with seeing what you've tried first.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at the `Split()` method of the string class.

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] toRemove = selectedFeatureIds.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
featuresDto.RemoveAll(f => toRemove.Contains(f.Id));
```

Comment: `IList<T>` doesn't have a `RemoveAll` method.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: Then either it must be changed to a `List<T>` or use `featuresDto.ToList().RemoveAll...` or (better) use a `foreach` instead: `foreach (int i in toRemove)
                featuresDto.RemoveAt(i);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = selectedFeatureIds.Split(',').Select(id => int.Parse(id)).ToList();
featuresDto.RemoveAll(feature => ids.Any(id => id == feature.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to put it:

```
featuresDto
    .Select((i, index) => 
        selectedFeatureIds.Split(',').Contains(i.Id.ToString()) ? index : -1)
    .Where(i => i >= 0)
    .OrderByDescending(i=>i)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => featuresDto.RemoveAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

First split your entrance string to array.

```
var ids = selectedFeatureIds.Split(',');
```

After that loop trough them and remove from List

```
foreach(var id in inds)
{
   featuresDto.Remove().Where(x => x.Id == Int32.Parse(id));
}
```

Comment: `Remove()` returns a `bool`, on which you can't call `Where()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster - thanks, it's good to have intellisense in VS ;) - it's hard to remember all methods. My answer was more about the concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a int array from selectedFeatureIds (use string split method)

```
foreach(int i in int_Ary)
{
  foreach(FeatureDto f in featuresDto){
   if(f.id == i)
    featuresDto.Remove(f)
  }

}
```